# Testing PhoneGap apps in a simulator browser with LiveReload

Tags: cordova, webview, ios-simulator, gruntjs, livereload

I'm working on PhongeGap app that is based on Ionic and is watched by Grunt.

I'm looking for a way to quickly review changes and integrate LiveReload into my workflow.
I don't want to have to re-build the app on every minor change to styles / markup.

My question is this:

When opening the PhoneGap web files in an iOS / Android simulator browser, 
are there any differences to the app webView other than the PhoneGap API not being available?

Is there a way to load resources from the local environment using PhoneGap instead of packaging them? I tried having an empty webView app pointing to a localhost port but could not get it to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Adobe PhoneGap team just released this great tool that does exactly what you are looking for!

http://app.phonegap.com/

I have used it a few times and it decreases dev time greatly! You can even have it running on multiple devices at once. So useful.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks for sharing Dawson.